# How to update Model value when trigger controller function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jqgrid

controller:

```
onSelectRow : 
       function(id){ 
            setTimeout(function () {$scope.getSelectedRow(); }, 0);
          },};

$scope.getSelectedRow = function(){

var grid = $("#patientgrid");

var rowKey = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam',"selrow");

var kelr = grid.jqGrid('getCell', rowKey, 'PostTopic');

if (rowKey)
{ 
     $scope.lastsel=kelr;   
}
else
alert("No rows are selected");}
```

Html:

```
 <h1>Topic:{{lastsel}}</h1>
```

Problem is ...
when I choose the new row, "lastsel" doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

I use $apply and it works!!

$scope.getSelectedRow = function(){

```
        var grid = $("#patientgrid");
        var rowKey = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam',"selrow");
        var kelr = grid.jqGrid('getCell', rowKey, 'PostTopic');
        if (rowKey)
        {
            $scope.lastsel; 
            $scope.$apply(function() 
            {
                $scope.lastsel=kelr;
            },1);  

           }
        else alert("No rows are selected");
    }
```